# Focus input then change outside div color

Tags: javascript, html, css

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/rVLbbW)**

You can see there is a little red color area. This red color is main `div` background color. And this `div` has `input` inside.

So if you click the red area then you can see the search icon changing background color. But when you click the input area then the color will not changing. What can I do here?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tt" tabindex="2">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Some text..."/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tt {
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  margin:0px auto;
  margin-top:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
.test {
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url(http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/nexusae0_search.png);
  background-size:50px;
   transition: transform(rotate);
    transition-duration: 400ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0, 0.150, 1);
}
.tt:focus .test{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url(http://ajkdjournal.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/e62f58b03dbcfda4a54f6bac1057305e.png);
}
.input{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  padding:18px;
  width:400px;
  text-indent:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some changes in the HTML and the CSS. I hope it helps [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNzEXe)

```
<div class="tt" tabindex="2">
    <!-- note I changed the HTML structure + added changes in the CSS -->
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Some text..."/>
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your input before the .test div, and then use the sibling selector (+). The code should be:

HTML:

```
<div class="tt" tabindex="2">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Some text..."/>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input:focus + .test{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url(http://ajkdjournal.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/e62f58b03dbcfda4a54f6bac1057305e.png);
}
```

Hope this help !